# At run-time, in objective-c, how do you place a UIObject into a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

At run-time, in objective-c, how to place a `UIObject` into a `UIView`?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "at run-time"?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Could you be more specific?  Taking a stab at what you're looking for, I'd say `addSubview` (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Comment: Lack of a better word...I am not using the Interface builder to place UI components.  It is all done in the code.  So I am not sure how to create 5 UIViews with 5 UI components in each one.

Comment: @jdl: You have 4 good solutions below.

Comment: @PengOne: All of them refer to the main UIview. I am creating and resizing 5 new UIViews and placing objects in each one.

Comment: @jdl: Where are you creating them? In a viewController? In the AppDelegate? Post some code and ask a specific question if you want more specific answers. We cannot read your mind. We can only read your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a UIObject in a UIView whenever you like so long as the view and object both exist (and you can create them if they don't). If the object is a subclass of UIView (which I assume it is), then just do:

```
[myView addSubview:myObject];
```

Place this code wherever you like, so long as both `myView` and `myObject` have already been created (with `alloc` and `init`, for example).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following --

```
UIImage *closeButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"closeButton.png"];
[closeButton setImage: closeButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:closeButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

When the main UIView loads it invokes `viewDidLoad` & `viewDidAppear`. You need to over-ride these methods & put your object creation in these methods.

Lets say you want to create a `UILabel` at runtime. You place the following code in `viewDidLoad` & your object gets created & added as a subview to the main view.

```
UILabel *newLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-150,0,50,15)];
[newLabel setText:@"Method: "];
newLabel.textAlignment    = UITextAlignmentLeft;
newLabel.backgroundColor  = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
newLabel.font             = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:11];
[self.view addSubview:newLabel];
[newLabel release];
```

You need not add (or create) UI objects only in these methods. If you have defined any gestures & have specified selector methods for them, you could create & add objects in those methods too...

Answer (score 1):

Allocate the UI like this for example

```
UIButton* btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[btn  setFrame:desiredFrame];
[view addSubview:btn];
```

Answer (score 0):

let your object be a Button, then use following code in your method(where you want to add object to `UIView`):

```
    UIButton *objectButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [objectButton setImage:actualImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [objectButton setTag:intValue];
    [objectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(anyMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addSubview:iconImageSlide];
```

here `[self addSubview:iconImageSlide];` add object to your view.